# CodeIgniter URL Routing with RegEx

Tags: regex, codeigniter, url-routing

I do URL routing in my project. I have a URL like this:

```
www.example.com/seller/list/active/name/asc/1
```

It means show me the first page of active seller list after ordering them by their name in ascending order. However, I also have to accept this and make it equal to the link above:

```
www.example.com/seller/list/name/asc
```

So I need a URL routing. I have tried this:

```
$route['seller/list/(?!active|passive)/(asc|desc)'] = "seller/list/active/$1/$2/1";
```

The problem is in `(?!active|passive)` part, it doesn't work. What I want to do is to select word if it is not `active` or `passive`. For example, it should select `name` in the second link. How can I realize this?

Comment: `(?!active|passive)` is a negative lookahead and consumes nothing ( zero width assertion) it is not a capturing group. i also notice you have `$1, $2 and $3` yet you only have one capturing group `(asc|desc)`

Comment: I corrected the error, thanks. So should I say `((?!active|passive).*?)` or alike? It seems to be working.

Comment: it's been a while since i've used CI routing, and i dont have a test enviroment...but try `seller/list/(active/|passive/)?name/(asc|desc)(/\d+)?`.

Comment: forgot to add that the route you are transforming to `seller/list/active/$1/$2/1` already has `active` in it so it seems CI's finally route would be `seller/list/active/active|passive/asc|desc/1` is this right or am i way off

Comment: If active or passive exists, I have to capture it to be able to copy the value into the new URL. Therefore your second comment is correct.